# Check if string is valid representation of hex number

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I am total noob regarding `regex`.

My goal is to check whether a string is a valid representation of a hex number.

Currently my implementation (which I find really inefficient) is having a List with all hex digits (0-9, A-F) and checking whether my string contains characters not contained in given List.

I bet this can be easily done using regular expressions but I have no idea how to implement it.

```
private bool ISValidHEX(string s)
{
    List<string> ToCheck = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ToCheck.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    ToCheck.Add("A");
    ToCheck.Add("B");
    ToCheck.Add("C");
    ToCheck.Add("D");
    ToCheck.Add("E");
    ToCheck.Add("F");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if( !ToCheck.Contains(s.Substring(i,1)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would have thought that it's quickest to attempt to convert your string to an integral type and deal with any exception. Use code like this:

```
int num = Int32.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

The resulting code is possibly easier to follow than a regular expression and is particularly useful if you need the parsed value (else you could use `Int32.TryParse` which is adequately documented in other answers).

(One of my favourite quotations is by Jamie Zawinski: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.")

Comment: +1. Or even the `TryParse` version - `Int32.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out myInt);`

Answer (score 15):

To simply check

> Check if string is valid represantion of HEX number

you may use a method like:

```
int res = 0; 
if(int.TryParse(val, 
         System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, 
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out res)) {

      //IT'S A VALID HEX
}
```

Pay attention on  `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` parameter, change it according to your needs.

Comment: @Bathsheba: not at all. try it.

Comment: I think `InvariantCulture` is exactly correct here. It's not like a hex string should accented characters, thousands separators or decimal points! Are there recognized cultural differences in hex numbers?

Comment: Another point to note is the length of the hex string. `int.TryParse` will fail if the string is over 8 characters long. `long.TryParse` will allow 16 characters.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx). 
There is an overload that allow the Hex numbers conversion

```
int v;
string test = "FF";
if(Int32.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out v))
   Console.WriteLine("Is HEX:" + v.ToString());
```

This is better than a simple Int32.Parse because, in the case that you have an invalid hex or the conversion overflows the Int32.MaxValue you don't get an exception but you could simply test the boolean return value.

Warning, the string cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&H"

Answer (score 2):

I tried Google search. I found lots of solutions. Here are two:

[Validate Hex Color Code with Regular Expression](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-hex-color-code-with-regular-expression/)

[Regular Expression Hexadecimal Number Validation](http://www.tipsntracks.com/150/regular-expressions-hexadecimal-number-validation-with-net.html)

Example

```
//use System.Text.RegularExpressions before using this function
public bool vldRegex(string strInput)
{
//create Regular Expression Match pattern object
Regex myRegex = new Regex("^[a-fA-F0-9]+$");
//boolean variable to hold the status
bool isValid = false;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInput))
{
   isValid = false;
}
else
{
   isValid = myRegex.IsMatch(strInput);
}
//return the results
return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Links are great, link only answers are not. Make sure you quote any relevant sections or give a usage example.

Comment: This answer was the one that worked best in my case, where I needed to test larger strings, in the format "5e580ab3285bae22d4157ede". For these cases, the other proposed solutions, presented an error when trying to convert to Int32.
Although it contains a little more code, I believe that this solution deserves to be marked as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

`^[0-9a-fA-F]+$` will match strings which are numbers and valid hex letters BUT this doesn't match the possible 0x at the front. I'm sure you can add that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your hex string will have a maximum of 32 characters (e.g. usually GUIDs fit this bill), then you could `PadLeft` the string with zeros to ensure it has always 32 characters and then use the `Guid.TryParse`

```
public static bool IsHex(string hexString)
{
    var isHex = false;
    if ((hexString ?? string.Empty).Length == 0)
        return false;
    if (hexString.Length > 0 && hexString.Length <= 32)
    {
        hexString = hexString.PadLeft(32, '0');
        Guid guid;
        isHex = Guid.TryParse(hexString, out guid);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Use some other way to check the hex string!");
    }
    return isHex;
}
```

Try it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/bLaCAT