# Is there a way to differentiate a string argument between non-hexadecimal and a hexadecimal?

Tags: c#

Let's say we have the following signature

```
void doSomething(string s)
```

When the user calls the function, they can call

`doSomething("hello")` or `doSomething("\x15\x3C\xFF")`

Is there a way to tell when the argument is the second form, a hexadecimal value?

I want to do something like

```
if(isHex(s))     
    // do this
else
    // do that
```

Comment: I think using regex can helps ;).

Comment: If you want to accept a hexadecimal value, why not just provide an overload that takes a numerical type?

Comment: Probable duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223832/check-a-string-to-see-if-all-characters-are-hexadecimal-values
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933590/check-if-string-is-valid-represantion-of-hex-number

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not allowed to use overloading. It must all be in one method.

Comment: The second string is only hexadecimal at the source level, the contents are whatever characters you get from those values. You can write "hello" like "\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F" it's completely indistinguishable. And therefore it is **not** a duplicate of the linked questions. The real answer is "no, there is no way to differentiate them", you'll have to come up with something else.

Comment: @harold You're correct. I tried those previous "duplicate" solutions, and they don't work. The program sees the original hex as "6\u0093h-E" (not exactly this form). I.E. everything is a string to the program, so it can't tell the difference whether the original was a hex or not.

Comment: So, do you have more context to this? What are some things that would be allowed? Can you mandate that all "hex strings" begin with a certain character that a normal string wouldn't reasonably begin with?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. To the runtime environment, a string is essentially just an array of characters (which is essentially just a collection of bytes). It has no idea how those characters were originally represented either in plain text or escaped sequences of hexadecimal.

Comment: This is what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in order to check for valid hex strings. But in order to do this you must provide the string in hex notation as is, i.e. without C#'s interpretation and transformation into a normal string. Use a verbatim string (introduced by a "@") for this:

```
string s =  @"\x15\x3C\xFF";
```

In verbatim strings, the backslashes are not interpreted as escape characters by c#. But the downside of this is that you are not getting the intended resulting string any more, of course.

```
public static bool IsHexString(string s)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(\\x[0-9A-F]{2})+$");
}
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

`^` beginning of string.
`\\` escaped backslash ("`\`"). Not a C# escape here, but a regex escape.
`x` the letter "x".
`[0-9A-F]{2}` two consecutive hex digits.
`(...)+` at least one occurence of a hex number.
`$` end of line.

Comment: This is different from what the question asked. The OP is asking if it's possible to determine if a string was *defined* with hexadecimal characters (not that he didn't use an `@` at the beginning of his sample string).