# Why "0x5" is not parsed as a valid Hex number?

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if a string contains a valid Hex number.

I'm using the approach documented in [Check if string is valid represantion of HEX number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933590/check-if-string-is-valid-represantion-of-hex-number/25933687).

With the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int temp;
        bool b = int.TryParse("0x5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out temp);
        System.Console.Write("{0} : {1}", b, temp);
    }
}
```

I'm getting: `False : 0` at the output.

What is wrong here?

Comment: It seems that it can't parse the "0x" part, if you just write for example int.TryParse("5"...) then it works (also int.TryParse("A"....) works).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_NumberStyles_AllowHexSpecifier):

> AllowHexSpecifier
>
> Indicates that the numeric string represents a hexadecimal value. Valid hexadecimal values include the numeric digits 0-9 and the hexadecimal digits A-F and a-f. **Strings that are parsed using this style cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&h".** A string that is parsed with the AllowHexSpecifier style will always be interpreted as a hexadecimal value. The only flags that can be combined with AllowHexSpecifier are AllowLeadingWhite and AllowTrailingWhite. The NumberStyles enumeration includes a composite style, HexNumber, that consists of these three flags.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Bad for me :)... i eventually used Regex to detect . thanks

Comment: Despite its name, `AllowHexSpecifier` does not allow any hex specifier. It just *interprets* the thing as hexadecimal. :-/