# Is there a method in c# to check if a string is a valid hexadecimal number?

Tags: c#

I wanted to add a manual hexadecimal input for a C# repository of mine, I had no way of verifying if the user's input was a legitimate ARGB hexadecimal value the user had entered into the textbox or if it was a garbage hexadecimal number. Does anyone have a potential solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933687/251311 ?

Comment: What UI framework are you working with?

Comment: .net Framework 4.8

Comment: Note that the input doesn't just needs to be a hex number, it also needs to be a valid ARGB value. So it must be exactly 8 chars long, unless you want to support a default value for the A (FFFFFF = opaque white) and/or "single digit bytes" (FFF = white)

Comment: What if the user was to input a non valid ARGB value such as #GGGGGG?

Comment: Since it's user input validation, it doesn't have to be performant. How this string is used afterwards? I guess you have a method which takes such string as an input. You can simply run this method inside `try/catch` to see if it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2109756/10216583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [regex](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221362/regular-expression-for-a-hexadecimal-number):

```
string pattern = @"^0[xX][0-9a-f]{8}$";
string input = "0x1a2b3C";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{...}
```

Comment: 1. the `0x` prefix is a c# thing, I doubt the users will use that. 2. If you're already going with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, there's no point of using `a-fA-F` in the pattern as well. 3. I think the `\g` here is not needed. Instead, you should use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, to indicate that the entire string should match the regular expression. 4. argb values are 8 digits long - so instead of `+` you should use `{8}`.

Answer (score -1):

So, I did a very inefficient method, I started off by making a pastebin with every single valid ARGB hex code, I then wrote the following:

```
WebClient Checker = new WebClient();
string List = Checker.Downloadstring("https://pastebin.com/raw/link");//link would be the pastebin
string Input = this.TextBox.Text;
if (List.Contains(Input))
{
   //submit write file code here
}
else
{
  System.Windows.Messagebox.Show("The Input Was Not Valid! Please Input A Valid ARGB Code!", "Error!");
}
```

This method ended up working for me. It isn't recommended but does the job right.